# Nodejs redis list pop issue

Tags: node.js, list, redis, spawn

Facing a problem in poping out redis list item from nodejs, below is the objective I am trying to achieve -

## Objective

- PHP is adding item in redis list (sorted) and publishing a flag on a channel.
- nodejs is subscribed to the channel and once a message is received it pops out all items in list.
- items poped out is pushed to a spawn process to process it further one by one, that means for each item present in list there will be a different process getting executed.

## Code

main.js

```
subscribe.on("message", function (channel, message) {
     client.lrange('mylist', 0, -1, function (error, messages) {
         messages.forEach(function (message, key, _array) {
         child[i] = spawn('node', ['process.js', i], {detached: true});
         child[i].stdin.write(message);
     }
}
```

process.js

```
setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('done');
    client.quit();
    process.exit(0);
}, 2500);
```

## Problem

If the list have one item it works fine, but if I kill the script and accumulate few items in list and then start nodejs script, few items from list go missing while processing.

Comment: Is the item that you're getting is the latest one and the others are missing ?

Comment: the position and number of items are not fixed

Comment: @Basit recently i have changed my approach from pubsub+fork to brpop. Not sure if it will work. can you please comment on that approach as well

Comment: which library are you using ?

Comment: redis i.e. redis = require('redis');